# asp.net dropdown menu items from sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, select, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUser" runat="server" CssClass="form-

control" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 

DataTextField="Person" DataValueField="PersonID" 

OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUser_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">

        <asp:ListItem>Select User</asp:ListItem>

        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="

<%$ ConnectionStrings:IBS_6 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT PersonID, PLName 

+ ' 

    ' + PFName + ',' + PMoNo AS Person, PFName, PLName, PMoNo, PEmail, PArea, 

PCity, PAge, PGender, PType, PStatus, dbTstamp FROM tbl_persons ORDER BY 

dbTstamp DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

if the value of any fields of file 'PMoNo' is blank or null then dropdown menu's item's display is blank. Howere the value of the item comes I can select the blank item.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PfMoNo is null, then also PfName + ‘,’ + PfMoNo is null, so DropDown sees Person null and does not display text. You should use
COALESCE(PfMoNo,‘’) instead of PfMoNo

Comment: This helped. Thanks.